# How to share cookies between two webviews of two different apps in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have two android Apps.My requirement the session/cookie maintained on APP1 , how to launch the app2 having same cookie.
Can two different apps with two different browser share the same cookie or can we have shared browser between two apps.